# Access forbidden based user role after change it

Tags: php, symfony, security, controller, restriction

In my website I want to give to some users the ability to change their role clicking a button. I implemented it in the following way:

```
$post = Request::createFromGlobals();
if($post->request->has('change') && $user->hasRole('ROLE_MEDIA') == False){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_MEDIA'));
        $em->flush();
 }
```

It is working fine, after check the database and I can recover in the main controller the flag without problems. The problem is the following: after clicking the button and access to restricted pages to users who have the ROLE_MEDIA,I am getting a 403 error. It seems that Symfony doesn't detect the new user role. I am restricting some pages using the following code:

```
/**
*
* @Security("has_role('ROLE_MEDIA')")
*/
```

I don't understand the problem because I can access the right values in my controller... Thanks in advance

Comment: try to check if you find a solution [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12025)

Comment: does it work after you logout and then log back in?

Comment: Thanks for the url you provided @VitaliyRyaboy !! I could find a solution there, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the easiest solution is to refresh session by regenerating session ID:

```
$post = Request::createFromGlobals();
if($post->request->has('change') && $user->hasRole('ROLE_MEDIA') == False){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_MEDIA'));
        $em->flush();
        $this->get('session')->migrate();
 }
```